# get maven plugin install location inside my mojo

Tags: maven

I have a mojo maven plugin. I need to capture the path where the project's jar was installed (inside local repository) if it was (during the build). Currently i only use MavenProject inside my mojo and getting all the needed information from there.
Couldn't find the install location from there though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven-install-plugin is resolving the installation path with this method:

```
  org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.pathOf(Artifact artifact)
```

So I guess you have to call it too, probably with something like this:

```
String artifactPath = localRepository.pathOf(mavenProject.getArtifact());
```

**EDIT**

here is how to get a reference to your local repository:

```
/**@parameter default-value="${localRepository}" */
private org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository localRepository;
```

from [this source](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook#MojoDeveloperCookbook-Foraccessingartifactsandrepositories)

Comment: Artifact.getRepository() returns null for me. If i list repositories with getPluginRepositories() it lists remote repositories only. Do you know where to get ArtifactRepository for local repository from?

Comment: Thanks, that's what i've missed. Worked well!